Basis of eigenfunction of nonself-adjoint operator
If $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, $A$ is a bounded nonself-adjoint operator, $\{\lambda_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and the corresponding eigenfunctions are $\{\psi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$. Suppose $\{\psi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a Schauder basis of $H$, can we get $\sigma(H)=\overline{\{\lambda_n\}}$? In the self-adjoint case, we can easily construct the inverse of $A-\lambda I$ if $\lambda\notin\overline{\{\lambda_n\}}$. In the non-self-adjoint case, for any $x\in H$, $x=\sum_nx_n\psi_n$. We can formally define $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}x=\sum_n\frac{x_n}{\lambda-\lambda_n}\psi_n$. But I don't know how to show it is a bounded operator.

By ${\psi_n}$ being a basis of $H$, do you mean it is an orthonormal basis?

It may not be orthonormal basis.

Then what do you mean by “basis”? In infinite dimensions there are many different notions of “basis”. You have to specify what you meant.

I mean the basis is a Schauder basis.

Do you assume $A$ is bounded?

Yes, $A$ is a bounded operator

I found an example. Take $H=\oplus_n \mathbb{C}^n$, $A=\oplus_nA_n$, $A_n=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    e^{i\alpha} & 1 &0&\cdots&0\\
    0 & e^{2i\alpha} &1&\cdots&0\\
  &&\cdots\\
 0& 0 &0&\cdots&e^{in\alpha}\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$. We can find that $\{e^{in\alpha}\}$ are the eigenvalues of $H$, and the corresponding eigenfunctions form a Schauder basis.
Set $B_n=\left [\begin{matrix}
    e^{i\alpha} & 0 &0&\cdots&0\\
    0 & e^{2i\alpha} &0&\cdots&0\\
  &&\cdots\\
 0& 0 &0&\cdots&e^{in\alpha}\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$, $C_n=\left [\begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 &0&\cdots&0\\
    0 & 0 &1&\cdots&0\\
  &&\cdots\\
 0& 0 &0&\cdots&0\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$,
Then $A_n^{-1}=(I+B_n^{-1}C_n)^{-1}B_n^{-1}=(I-(B_n^{-1}C_n)^{2}+\cdots+(-1)^{n}(B_n^{-1}C_n)^{n-1})B_n^{-1}.$
It is easily to see that $\|A_n^{-1}e_n\|=\sqrt{n}$, this means $H$ is not invertible, i.e. $0\in\sigma(H)$.
